# Django, Postgresql Aggregate By Month Function is Also Using Year

Tags: django, postgresql, aggregation

I have a database table that contains "tickets" over a 2 year period. Each ticket has a work date. I want a count of the total number of tickets in each month by year (e.g Jan 2018 being different from Jan 2019).

As I was cobbling together the query, I stumbled on something that worked, but I do not know why. Or if the query makes sense. Here it is:

```
qs = Ticket.filter(work_date__range=[datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 
datetime.date.today()]).\
annotate(year=ExtractYear('work_date'), 
month=ExtractMonth('work_date')).\
values('year','month').\
annotate(count=Count('month')).order_by('year', 'month')
```

Giving this output:

```
{'count': 13816, 'year': 2018, 'month': 1},
{'count': 12778, 'year': 2018, 'month': 2}, 
{'count': 13960, 'year': 2018, 'month': 3},
{'count': 14128, 'year': 2018, 'month': 4}, 
{'count': 15277, 'year': 2018, 'month': 5}, 
{'count': 15689, 'year': 2018, 'month': 6}, 
{'count': 14905, 'year': 2018, 'month': 7}, 
{'count': 16025, 'year': 2018, 'month': 8}, 
{'count': 14044, 'year': 2018, 'month': 9}, 
{'count': 16332, 'year': 2018, 'month': 10}, 
{'count': 15397, 'year': 2018, 'month': 11}, 
{'count': 14348, 'year': 2018, 'month': 12}, 
{'count': 17166, 'year': 2019, 'month': 1}, 
{'count': 15504, 'year': 2019, 'month': 2}, 
{'count': 16311, 'year': 2019, 'month': 3}, 
{'count': 14910, 'year': 2019, 'month': 4}, 
{'count': 440, 'year': 2019, 'month': 5}
```

My expectation is that since the aggregating function is only counting by 'month' that, for example all month 1's would be in the same count, regardless of year.

I have run a simple query by month and used the .count() method and I get the same results as above. So the counts are correct.

Why does this work? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get groups by year/month combination since these are your values. If you want to get count by month, then change the `values('year','month')` to `values('month')`.

The count is just the field you are counting. 
You can count the 'id' instead and you will get the same numbers.
You can always look the the generated query, this might make things clearer for you.

```
print(qs.query)
```

Comment: Good answer.  For more info, just thought I'd point to [the doc on `values` in aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values)